# How do you linearize this nonlinear system?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

The system equations are:

$$
\ddot{\theta} = -\alpha \; |\theta| \; \theta + \sin(\theta) - \tau
$$
$$
\tau(t) = 20 \; e^{-20t} \; v(t)
$$

The system state space description is:

$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ 
x_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\theta \\ 
\dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
u = v
$$
$$
y = \theta
$$

The equilibrium values are $\alpha = -1,14$, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$, $\dot{\theta} = 0$ and $v(t) = 0$.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE!. Please visit the [tour] page if you have not already done so. Please improve your question by [edit]ing it. Please mention what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showing some effort on your part will likely yield answers from others

Answer (score 0):

If we rewrite the system under the input affine form:
$$\dot{x}=f(x)+g(t)v$$
i.e.
$$\left[\begin{array}{c} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} x_2 \\ -\alpha |x_1|x_1+\sin(x_1)\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -20e^{-20t}\end{array}\right]v $$
The input-free system is at an equilibrium for all $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. In particular if $x_2=0$, $x_1=\pi/4$, and $\alpha=8 \sqrt{2}/\pi^2 \approx 1.146318...$, one can indeed check that $f(x)=0$.

The linearization of the input-free system is provided by the Jacobian of $f$ evaluated at the equilibrium $(x_1,x_2)=(\pi/4,0)$.

For all $x_1\neq 0$, the Jacobian is given by:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_1,x_2) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -2\alpha |x_1|+\cos(x_1) & 0\end{array}\right]$$
Hence evaluated at $(x_1,x_2)=(\pi/4,0)$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\pi/4,0) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ (\sqrt{2}-\alpha \pi)/2 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

We obtain the following linearization:
$$\left[\begin{array}{c} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ (\sqrt{2}-\alpha \pi)/2 & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -20e^{-20t}\end{array}\right]v $$

However, note that the input matrix is time-varying. This can easily be fixed by re-introducing $\tau$ with $$v(t)= \frac{e^{20t}}{20}\tau(t)$$

In the end:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ (\sqrt{2}-\alpha \pi)/2 & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -1\end{array}\right]\tau $$